# Computer halts when trying to install any Linux distro?

Tags: ubuntu, fedora, live-usb

This is a follow up a post is initially created in [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/842405/ubuntu-16-04-installation-freezes-when-loading-the-system)

I have tried to install Ubuntu, Xubuntu and Fedora on a MSI GL62 6QF-632NL with Intel Core i7-6700HQ and NVIDIA GeForce GTX 960M to no avail. Ubuntu and Xubuntu halt midway the installation process and our most recent attempt with Fedora produced the following error when checking the disk:

[image]
[image]

Someone has a guess of what my be causing this problem. I have done everything that is recommended (create a partition to store Linux, disable the UEFI and Windows fast-startup, but nothing seems to solve the problem).

Comment: Are you installing from a USB device?  If so, have you tried using a different device?

Comment: If you are planning to dual boot Linux and Windows, don't disable UEFI.

Comment: @Flup Yes, I tried with two different USBs.

Answer (score 1):

The error message suggests that your installation medium is corrupt.

Check the fingerprint of the downloaded ISO image. If it is OK check if the USB creation issues an error.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with Fedora 25 freezing on an MSI GP60. Once it froze during install, but I tried again and it stayed up long enough to install but kept freezing when I tried to use it. I solved it by changing PCI Latency Timer from 32 clocks to 64 clocks in BIOS.

I also disabled Speed Step in BIOS, but after I got the system stabilized, I tried turning it back on and I haven't crashed yet.